# What mission(s) do I have to finish to access Murderlin's Temple (slaughter arena)?

Tags: borderlands-2, borderlands-2-tiny-tinas-assault

In the 'Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep' DLC, one of my characters got the 'Find Murderlin's Temple' mission, which allows passage to the Murderlin's Temple [slaughter arena](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/119966/4797).

However, I didn't notice which mission is the pre-requisite of the 'Find Murderlin's Temple' mission. I would like to go to Murderlin's Temple using another character of mine which doesn't have access yet.

Which mission(s) do I have to finish to access Murderlin's Temple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, My friend, Having beaten the new DLC on each playthrough with my krieg, I can tell you that the answer is...

You have to beat all of the story missions.

Answer (score 2):

I beat the main mission. And it was available after that. You need to talk to Moxxi in her tavern. She gives you the quest to find Murderlin.

Answer (score 0):

You have to complete all of the story missions in Tiny Tina's DLC. Murderlin's Temple can then be accessed through Flamerock Refuge, which is down a ramp near Torgue (if I remember correctly).